# my first napa app office

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, office-web-apps, napa

This is my first time with Napa to create APP sharepoint .
in my app , I want to add lists, uploads images ,forum , and many other social option.
If any one know how can I do it?. best regrads

Answer (score 1):

Via NAPA you won't be able as NAPA tools are quite limited. With regards to SharePoint Apps you can only create SharePoint-hosted, and cannot create Content types, list definitions, etc - which is what you need.

Therefore, i recommend to get at least a Trial VS full license (you need at least Professional) and install Office tools (if you get the latest VS2013 + update 2 these are already in) and open the project in Visual Studio using the button on the toolbar.

Once in VS you'll get MOST of these options.